# Are RAID formats compatible across distributions?

Tags: ubuntu, fedora, raid, freenas, nas

I'm planning a NAS/home media server build, probably with a HP Proliant Microserver. It will probably have two HDDs in RAID 1, while the OS while run from a USB drive.

Question is: once I've set up the RAID drives, can I swap the OS for something completely different and expect it to keep working? Let's say swapping between FreeNAS, Ubuntu, Fedora, XPEnology...

EDIT

In light of the two responses so far, I think my question should probably have been:

**What is a good choice of software RAID to ensure maximum compatibility across distributions**?

Comment: I think the microServer comes with a hardware RAID controller, so probably proprietary RAID management.

Comment: Would all distros know how to talk to the hardware RAID? (Sorry if dumb question...)

Comment: For sure, all recent distros have support for it. I've been using redhat 4, 5, 6 on proliant servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to create a SoftRAID with Linux: LVM's internal RAID and four versions of MD RAID (`mdadm`): 0.90, 1.0, 1.1, 1.2.

Every non-ancient Linux should understand them all. There should not be any problem with a distro change.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to LVM internal RAID and `mdadm` RAID that Hauke mentioned [Btrfs](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/FAQ#What_are_the_differences_among_MD-RAID_.2F_device_mapper_.2F_btrfs_raid.3F) and [ZFS](http://www.zfsbuild.com/2010/05/26/zfs-raid-levels/) have RAID support built-in.

Btrfs has RAID-0, RAID-1, RAID-10 and staring with Linux 3.9 RAID-5 and RAID-6.
Those are in compatible with other Btrfs version with at least the same version.

ZFS has RAID-0, RAID-1, RAID-10, RAID-5, RAID-6, RAID-0 under different names, as well as a RAIDZ3 which has three parity entries (where RAID-5 has one and RAID-6 has two).

Both these filesystem specific RAIDs are incompatible with each other and the other RAID capability "providers" (LVM/mdadm).